# book cover: a planet which has a creepy smiling face of a girl

Tags: story-identification, books, planets

I only remember the cover. I am pretty sure it was a sequel in some series. Definitely young adult. It was a girl's face on the surface of a planet just smiling creepily. I think it must be some popular YA series, but I don't know about it. Came out around 2019-2020

I am pretty sure it is **fantasy** but since it has planets on the cover it could be a sci-fi. The first book in that series did not have a similar cover though. I don't remember the author's name nor the book title and not even the series name. I was just intrigued by the cover.

Comment: Lots of books have [planets on the cover](https://www.scholastic.com/teachers/books/my-book-of-planets-by-elise-see-tai/) that aren't fantasy or sci-fi. I think we need more here.

Comment: Something like [this](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/512K%2BvSnywL.jpg)?   (Note: not smiling)  Can you give us an idea of the colour?  Which direction she's facing?  Was the planet centred?  Occupying a substantial fraction of the cover?  Was the face superimposed on the planet?  Anything?

Comment: Also:  You can search yourself; [here is a list of publishers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_science_fiction_publishers); [here is a search page](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_selection.cgi?publisher).  Enter a name, select "Starts With" and search.  Click through to the publisher page, pick "2020" or "2019" in the "Years When Books Were Published" table and "View covers for this year"

Comment: Major (current) publishers are Ace, Baen, DAW, Del Rey, HarperCollins, Orbit and Tor; there are some others like Berkley, St. Martin's and Subterranean that are also publishing a reasonable number of books.